# "Optimized" TIFF file render slower than big original in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, dem

I struggle to "optimize" my rasters for publication on GeoServer.
My original raw GeoTIFF raster render before my "optimized" and I don't understand why?

The original file is at 18GB, Float32, size 69674, 67700

The "optimised" was created by

```
gdal_translate -a_nodata 0 -of GTiff -ot UInt16 -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" -co "TILED=YES" in.tif out.tif
```

It is at 0.56 GB. But despite this the original file is still rendered first, not by much but the "optimization" I have applied seem useless??

gdalinfo original file

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: original.tif
Size is 69674, 67700
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N",
    BASEGEOGCRS["ETRS89",
        DATUM["European Terrestrial Reference System 1989",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4258]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 32N",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",9,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["Europe - 6┬░E to 12┬░E and ETRS89 by country"],
        BBOX[38.76,6,83.92,12]],
    ID["EPSG",25832]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (551670.689999999944121,7038332.250000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.500009499956943,-0.500009500738550)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  551670.690, 7038332.250) ( 10d 2'12.57"E, 63d28'10.61"N)
Lower Left  (  551670.690, 7004481.607) ( 10d 1'33.45"E, 63d 9'57.09"N)
Upper Right (  586508.352, 7038332.250) ( 10d44' 8.05"E, 63d27'46.25"N)
Lower Right (  586508.352, 7004481.607) ( 10d43' 2.59"E, 63d 9'33.04"N)
Center      (  569089.521, 7021406.928) ( 10d22'44.17"E, 63d18'53.28"N)
Band 1 Block=69674x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
```

"Optimized"

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: optimized.tif
Size is 69674, 67700
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N",
    BASEGEOGCRS["ETRS89",
        DATUM["European Terrestrial Reference System 1989",
            ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4258]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 32N",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",9,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["Europe - 6┬░E to 12┬░E and ETRS89 by country"],
        BBOX[38.76,6,83.92,12]],
    ID["EPSG",25832]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (551670.689999999944121,7038332.250000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.500009499956943,-0.500009500738550)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  551670.690, 7038332.250) ( 10d 2'12.57"E, 63d28'10.61"N)
Lower Left  (  551670.690, 7004481.607) ( 10d 1'33.45"E, 63d 9'57.09"N)
Upper Right (  586508.352, 7038332.250) ( 10d44' 8.05"E, 63d27'46.25"N)
Lower Right (  586508.352, 7004481.607) ( 10d43' 2.59"E, 63d 9'33.04"N)
Center      (  569089.521, 7021406.928) ( 10d22'44.17"E, 63d18'53.28"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=0
```

Comment: what does gdalinfo say about the first file? are you rendering the whole file? or just small parts of it?

Comment: Thank you for patiently following so many questions here Ian! I have added the output from gdalinfo.
I am rendering at all zoom levels just to try it. It take longer time to render when zoomed out of course, but a huge difference in time. When i zoom in it render faster (pretty fast, happy with performance publishing as a wms) but the orgininal file still render just a bit quicker. I have added the layers as wms in both QGIS and in a simple leaflet map to test the speed

Comment: Neither of the two files have pyramids associated with them. As such, you aren't really helping it. You should do a 'gdaladdo -r average in.tif 2 4 8 16 32' before your optimization, and during your optimization, you should also do '-co COPY_SRC_OVERVIEWS=YES'

Comment: I'd try leaving the data as float32 as a first step - though that's just a guess on my part

Comment: @Ian using the original float32 actually did it actually very slightly faster. The file size just got 80mb larger so its clear how much work compression does. Mikkel You are right, I have not built overviews (yet). I just thought that the size of the file size would make a bigger difference at least not for 1 band rasters. I expected file size to have a greater effect on how long time rendering took. Thats interesting though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in comments, you likely need to build overviews.

Overviews and inner tiling optimize two different types of access:

- Having overviews optimizes the most the case when you're trying to look at the the whole raster on a small map, that is, the case where the GIS software needs to produce an output image that's smaller than the original raster. Overviews allow reading a similarly small image, avoiding excess read and expensive downsampling.
- Just having tiling optimizes the location of a small (tiny!) area out of a large raster, so the exact opposite case, it speeds up viewing the raster then you're looking at it at its native resolution.

The best situation is when you have both, inner tiling for the base level, and overviews that are tiled for lower zoom level access.

Then you have compression in the mix. That is another trade off, it trades less IO for higher CPU usage. Whether that brings a speed up, it's relative to the balance of your hardware. Are you accessing the raster on a slow network disk? Go for compression. You have lots of fast local storage and your CPU is weak? Don't compress. Your real world situation will likely need tests to determine what is the best scenario for you.

Comment: That's a great sumarized answer to a lot of reading I have done lately.